# create extension postgis in Python

Tags: python, postgis

Python 2.7

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    app = Flask(__name__)
    os.system("dropdb biobreak")
    os.system("createdb biobreak")
    os.system("CREATE EXTENSION postgis")
```

On the last line I get this error:

(env) vagrant@vagrant:biobreak$ python seed.py

sh: 1: CREATE: not found

I tried importing subprocess by the syntax was driving me crazy.

EDIT:

I tried the following command:

```
import subprocess
    cr_ext = "create extension postgis;"
    try:
        subprocess.check_call([
                'psql', '-q',
                '-U', 'vagrant',
                '-f', 'cr_ext',
                'biobreak'
            ])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
        print "Failed to invoke psql: {}".format(ex)
```

Got this error:

cr_ext: No such file or directory
Failed to invoke psql: Command '['psql', '-q', '-U', 'vagrant', '-f', 'cr_ext', 'biobreak']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working. Instead of a variable, my command needs to be in a file. Hence, the No file or directory error message. cr_ext.sql=> 'create extension postgis;'

Here is the working code:

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_call([
        'psql', '-q',
        '-U', 'vagrant',
        '-f', '/home/vagrant/src/projects/biobreak/cr_ext.sql',
        'biobreak'
    ])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
    print "Failed to invoke psql: {}".format(ex)
```